# Ouput DisplayVersion Property

Tags: powershell

I need to output the property of the Variable DisplayVersion which contains the version of the application in the result how do I do that in foreach loop?

```
$programList = @(
    'SAP'
    'Tanium'
    'Sentinel'
    'DisplayLink'
    'Cisco AnyConnect'
    'Adobe Acrobat Reader'
    'Google'
    'Lotus Notes'
    'Java Runtime'
    'My IT Windows'
    'Qualys'
    'Snow'
    'LogRhythm'

    )

$Regpath = @(
    'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
    'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
)

$installedPrograms = (Get-ItemProperty $Regpath).where({$_.DisplayName})
$result = foreach($program in $programList)
{
    $check = $installedPrograms.DisplayName -match $program
    if($check)
    {
        foreach($match in $check)
        {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Program = $program
                Status = 'Found'
                Match = $match
         
            }
        }
        continue
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Program = $program
        Status = 'Not Found'
        Match = $null
        version = $null
    }
}

$result
```

The output should look something like

```
Program              Status    Match                                   Version                        
-------              ------    -----                                   -------
SAP                  Found     SAP GUI for Windows 7.60  (Patch 4)     7.60.4
```

Comment: `get-package` will do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the version just match the displayname back to its corresponding object `$installedPrograms.Where({$PSItem.DisplayName -eq $match}).DisplayVersion`

```
[pscustomobject]@{
    Program = $program
    Status = 'Found'
    Match = $match
    Version = $installedPrograms.Where({$PSItem.DisplayName -eq $match}).DisplayVersion   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can approach the logic for your code, making use of [`Group-Object -AsHashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-7-group-objects-in-a-hash-table) and a maybe a [PowerShell `class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.2) (personal preference here).

```
$programList = @(
    'SAP'
    'Tanium'
    'Sentinel'
    'DisplayLink'
    'Cisco AnyConnect'
    'Adobe Acrobat Reader'
    'Google'
    'Lotus Notes'
    'Java Runtime'
    'My IT Windows'
    'Qualys'
    'Snow'
    'LogRhythm'
)

$Regpath = @(
    'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
    'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
)

$installedPrograms = (Get-ItemProperty $Regpath).where({ $_.DisplayName }) |
    Group-Object DisplayName -AsHashTable -AsString

class Thing {
    [string] $Program
    [string] $Status = 'Not Found'
    [string] $Match
    [string] $Version

    Thing() { }
    Thing([string] $Program, [string] $DisplayName, [string] $Version) {
        $this.Program = $Program
        $this.Status  = 'Found'
        $this.Match   = $DisplayName
        $this.Version = $Version
    }
}

$result = foreach($program in $programList) {
    if($keys = $installedPrograms.Keys -match [regex]::Escape($program)) {
        foreach($key in $keys) {
            $match = $installedPrograms[$key]
            [Thing]::new($program, $match.DisplayName, $match.DisplayVersion)
        }
        continue
    }
    [Thing]@{ Program = $program }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get-package from powershell 5.1 does something just like that, with an array and wildcards [how do I turn off the italics?].

```
get-package *chrome*,*notepad++*,*vlc*

Name                           Version          Source                 ProviderName
----                           -------          ------                 ------------
Notepad++ (64-bit x64)         7.8.9                                   msi
Google Chrome                  107.0.5304.107                          msi
VLC media player               3.0.11                                  Programs
```